# Where to find latest videos of colloquia or other talks in your field?

Tags: online-resource, seminars, audio-video-recording

I am wondering how I can find and keep updated of the latest colloquia and talks videos. I imagine that schools may take videos of talks they hosted and upload them somewhere. Of course not every school/department does this, and this depends on the field that one is interested in. But if I know where they are, I can check for updates manually, or set up some sort of feed/automated notification with keyword filtering.

To be more clear I am not looking for videos of online classes (e.g., http://coursera.org), but talks about the latest work in one's field.

The only ones that I found are [Stanford](https://www.youtube.com/user/stanfordonline/) and [UC Irvine](https://www.youtube.com/user/UCITLTC), but I suspect there must be more out there that are not on youtube.

Comment: In many life sciences conferences it is standard to present unpublished material, but in contrast to some other fields there is no associated publication. As a result, many conferences do not record talks, and those that do usually make them available only to participants.

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematics

From my experience not very many schools record talks as a matter of policy. But the special institutes often do.

- [MSRI](https://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos) has videos available for workshops dating back to at least 2004.
- [Fields Institute](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive) also has a large collection.
- [Newton Institute](https://www.newton.ac.uk/webseminars) records almost all of its seminars and colloquiums.
- [IHP](https://www.youtube.com/user/PoincareInstitute) has a Youtube Channel, and if you follow them on Google+ you get updates (sometimes even hourly) on new videos.
- [Clay](http://www.claymath.org/publications/video-catalogue) records their research conferences.
- [Simons Center for Geometry and Physics](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/multimedia/videos) no longer maintains a central list of videos. But if you visit the individual [workshop](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/scientific/workshops) pages the videos are made available very soon after the talks.
- [QGM (Centre for Quantum Geometry of Moduli Spaces)](http://qgm.au.dk/) records their conferences and master classes.
- [Banff International Research Station (BIRS)](http://www.birs.ca/videos/) makes conference/workshop videos available.

Comment: (marked as CW, feel free to edit and add new Math ones)

Answer (score 2):

[videolectures.net](http://videolectures.net) hosts a large collection on a wide variety. They started as more computer science oriented (I usually watch the machine learning ones), but there are also other fields of study.

I've seen some major conferences and workshops utilize youtube lately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one web site that I found: [Berkeley Institute for Data Science](http://bids.berkeley.edu/resources/videos).